# Can a Visual Studio Snippet contain multiple shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, code-snippets

I've trawled through the [code snippet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets-schema-reference?view=vs-2019#shortcut-element) and can't find anything that says you can do this but thought I would ask anyway.

Consider the following snippet that adds a context menu TagHelper to a page:

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <Title>Context Menu</Title>
    <Author>UX</Author>
    <Shortcut>c:contextmenu</Shortcut>
    <Description>Markup snippet for a context menu</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Code Language="html">
      <![CDATA[<component:context-menu id="contextMenu">
            <context-menu-trigger>$end$</context-menu-trigger>
            <context-menu-content></context-menu-content>
        </component:context-menu>]]>
    </Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

I've tried multiple shortcut tags:

```
<Shortcut>c:contextmenu</Shortcut>
<Shortcut>c:context-menu</Shortcut>
```

I've tried separating them with a comma:

```
<Shortcut>c:contextmenu,c:context-menu</Shortcut>
```

No joy, I assume it can't be done and that I would have to create two snippets; one for each shortcut?

Comment: I can further confirm VS (2019) doesn't like this. I tried separating with spaces and semicolons, and I even tried moving the `<Snippet>` element to a separate file, to then [include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312009/reuse-xml-element-from-other-file) it into two separate files for the different shortcuts - VS throws a null ref error. :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done.  I found out by accident, but if you create multiple snippets with the same shortcut, when you use that shortcut you will get a pop-up giving you the option of which snippet do you want to run.